# Android: Update sms type after message has been sent

Tags: android, sms, android-contentresolver

I am trying to do this by writing this code

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Sms.TYPE, Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT);
context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms"), values, Sms.THREAD_ID+"=? AND "+Sms._ID+"=?", new String[]{thread_id,_id);
```

but no luck! this is not working.

so, help would be appericiated.